# R - How to log messages to file AND console

Tags: r, error-handling

I want to copy all messages (such as errors and warnings) to a file, but still have them output to the console as well, so something like sink() will not work. Additionally, I would like the messages in the file to come with a line number or other location identifier, such as:

```
Line 20: There were 18 warnings(use warnings() to see them)
```